# Why np.shape() for 1D-array doesn't produce 2 digit tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Based on my understanding of the np.shape() function, the function returns a tuple with each index having the number of adjacent elements.

When I run np.shape() on 2D-array:

```
a = np.array(([5,6,2,5],[7,8,9,10]))
print(np.shape(a))
```

I get (2, 4)

However, when I run np.shape() on 1D-array:

```
d = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(np.shape(d))
```

I get (6,)

Why isn't the answer (1,)? Because the 2D-array above represented 2 rows, 4 cols. Here in the 1D-array, I only have 1 row. I'm guessing that the 6 represents the 6 elements in the 1D array.

I'm aware of the definition where it returns the number of adjacent elements. However, even this contradicts the 2 rows, 4 cols answer because it didn't take into account the elements.

Can someone help clarify my doubts please. Thank you.

Comment: "Why isn't the answer (1,)?" -- because that would be rather useless. The array has 1 dimension and you want to know its size, which is 6.

Comment: "didn't take into account the elements" -- not sure what you mean by that. However, that is a 2 dimensional array, and numpy by default uses row major ordering. That array holds 2 rows, each of which has 4 columns.

Comment: `([5,6,2,5],[7,8,9,10])` -- the top-level element is tuple, holding 2 lists. That's your two rows (those come first). Then at the second level, you have `[5,6,2,5]` -- that's the 4 columns. All the other rows are expected to have the same number of columns.

Comment: And `np.shape(np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]))` returns a triplet, `(2,2,3)`. That starts with 2, because there are two layers of 2 rows and 3 columns. So why does `np.shape(np.array(([5,6,2,5],[7,8,9,10])))` doesn't return a tuple starting with 1, since on this 2d matrix there is only one layer? That is the same exact question.

Comment: A (1,6) shape is 1 'row' , 6 'columns'.  (6,) is a 1 element `tuple` (brush up on basic python if that isn't clear)., a `1d` array with 6 elements.  (2,3) is another shape with 6 elements. (6,1) also.

Comment: `a.size` is the total number of elements in the array.  `a.shape` is a `tuple`, describing the multidimensional 'layout' of the array, one tuple element per dimension.

Comment: @DanMašek thank you for the response. Replying to your 2nd comment on 2 rows and 4 columns hence forming the shape (2,4) for the 2D array. In the case of the 1D array, why isn’t the shape (1,6)? Because I have 1 row and 6 columns. That is my confusion.

Comment: In this case you configured it to have a single dimension. To be able to distinguish between rows and columns, you would need two. The number of elements in the tuple returned by `shape` corresponds to the number of dimensions of the numpy array. I mean, you could configure the numpy array to interpret the same 6-element data buffer as a 2D, in which case you could make it either (1,6), or (6,1).. or 3D as any permutation of (1,1,6), etc. | e.g. `d = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])` gives you the (1,6) shape. (Note the extra pair of square brackets)

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, describing a 1D-array as N elements in 1 row is correct but `np.shape()` is arbitrarily defined to provide clear information on the dimensions of the array. In the [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html), it says that the returned " elements of the shape tuple give the lengths of the corresponding array dimension". Array dimension in Numpy and programming, in general, is based on how many times you nest an array into a bigger array. Thus, this would return `(1,6)`:

```
np.shape(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6]]))
```

since there's one array nested into another.